# how to accelerate the speed of fetch cursor in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a big table(over billion records) in postgresql to process. I need to iterate over every record in this table. So, I use cursor. But the cursor fetch record one by one from database, which is every slow.

If I can fetch 20000 records from cursor everytime, it may speed up the performance. So, how to make it. I have wrote a pseudo code blow, but it can not be compiled.

Or, is there another better way to speed up the performance?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample.annovar_ods_sor_test(_sample_id integer)
  RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  tmp RECORD;
  ods_cursor CURSOR(my_sample_id INTEGER) FOR SELECT *
             FROM sample.ods_annovar
             WHERE sample_id = my_sample_id;
  tmp_ods RECORD ARRAY;
BEGIN

  OPEN ods_cursor(my_sample_id=_sample_id);
  <<ods_loop>>
  LOOP 
    FETCH RELATIVE 20000 FROM ods_cursor INTO tmp_ods;
    IF tmp_ods = NULL THEN
      EXIT ods_loop;
    END IF;
    FOR tmp IN tmp_ods LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE '%', tmp."Start";
      -- do something with the record
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP ;
  CLOSE ods_cursor;
  RETURN 1;
END
$$;
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do when iterating all the rows?  Reason asking is: The fastest way is not to iterate it.

Comment: Right, the fastest thing would be to do it all with one SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FOR IN SELECT` statement - it uses cursor internally. Is not possible to iterate over query result faster.

Comment: the `for in select` is the origin solution, but it is too slow.

Comment: @hellojinjie - nothing will be faster.